# How can I make flow to be run by specific user only?

Tags: visual-workflow, permissions, security, permission-sets

I have a button on opportunity record page which calls a flow, I want the flow to be accessed by specific set of users and no other user should be able to run the flow except admins. Is it possible? I don't want to change the profile settings.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can create a custom permission and assign it to permission set. And on the opportunity record page you can control the visibility of the button using dynamic forms based on permission set.